# Using VS2010 website template with an existing database?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Sorry if this is an obvious question, but my knowledge of asp.net is a bit patchy.

I need to make a quick website to act as a web frontend to some software I have made. I just created a website from the Asp.Net website template in VS2010, and was pleasantly suprised to see that this template comes almost fully built - for instance, when handling user registration/login.

However, I need the user registration/login system to go through an existing SQL Server database I have created. How do I set this up?

I tried changing the connection string from the default:

```
<add name="ApplicationServices"
 connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
 providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

to this:

```
<add name="ApplicationServices"
 connectionString="Server=MININT-8PNI9PD\SQLEXPRESS;Database=CourtListNotifier; Integrated Security=SSPI;"
 providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

However, this doesn't work - the site complains about missing a required stored procedure.

How do I solve this? I want to get the site working as quickly as possible, and so I want to change the template only a little to meet my needs, without using lots of time to write a large customized login system.

Comment: The existing SQL database that you created must obey certain schema. You cannot just use any database you like. You can use the `aspnet_regsql.exe` utility to create such database. Or if you want to use some custom database you will have to modify and use a custom MemberShip provider.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Great, `aspnet_regsql.exe` did the trick. It can be used to add membership details to an existing database, as well as creating a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`aspnet_regsql.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862.aspx) utility to create a database that obeys the required schema.